# dplyr summarise for multiple input values for a user defined function

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I have a dataframe `df` for which I want to identify the proportion of unique values in `col1` which satisfies a condition in `col2`.

```
set.seed(137)
df <- data.frame(col1 = sample(LETTERS, 100, TRUE), 
                 col2 = sample(-75:75, 100, TRUE), 
                 col3 = sample(-75:75, 100, TRUE))

df$col2[c(23, 48, 78)] <- NA
df$col3[c(37, 68, 81)] <- NA
```

For example, I want to find all the unique values in `col1` which have values in `col2` within the range of `-10` to `10` inclusive.

```
df %>%  
  mutate(unqCol1 = n_distinct(col1)) %>% 
  group_by(col1) %>% 
  mutate(freq = sum(between(col2, -10, 10), na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  filter(freq > 0) %>% distinct(col1, unqCol1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%  
  summarise(nrow(.)/unqCol1) %>% 
  unique()
```

which results in:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  `nrow(.)/unqCol1`
              <dbl>
1             0.423
```

Though the above code snippet is *not an efficient way* of doing it, I tried to achieve the result in single piped-command and it provides me the right output (*any clever ways of rewriting the above code are highly appreciatable*). I have reconfirmed the output using a base R approach:

```
length(unique(df$col1[df$col2 >= -10 & df$col2 <= 10 & !is.na(df$col2)]))/length(unique(df$col1))
```

I would like to re-write the above dplyr code within a function so that it could be replicated with multiple values of n (here: `n=10`) for the range (for multiple columns too). Is this possible? Or should I pass multiple values within the code itself (without function) like *apply-family* idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed, your (dplyr) code is overly complicated. You can compute the proportion of interest without grouping the data:

```r
df %>% 
  tidyr::drop_na() %>%
  filter(between(col2, -10, 10)) %>% 
  summarize(prop = n_distinct(col1) / n_distinct(df$col1))
```

A function for computing the proportion is:

```r
my_summary <- function(df, ...) {
   df %>% 
     tidyr::drop_na() %>%
     filter(...) %>% 
     summarize(
       prop = n_distinct(col1) / n_distinct(df$col1)
     )
}
```

E.g.

```r
> my_summary(df, between(col2, -10, 10))
       prop
1 0.4230769
```

gives the proportion in your question.

**EDIT**

You can vectorize `my_summary()` and use `outer()` to get a matrix of proportions for combinations of `col` and `n`:

```r
my_summary <- function(col, n) {
  df %>% 
    tidyr::drop_na() %>%
    filter(between(!!as.name(col), -n, n)) %>% 
    summarize(
      prop = n_distinct(col1) / n_distinct(df$col1)
    )
}
my_summary_v <- Vectorize(my_summary)
```

```r
> outer(c("col2", "col3"), c(10, 20, 30), my_summary_v)
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     
[1,] 0.4230769 0.5384615 0.6538462
[2,] 0.4230769 0.6538462 0.6923077
```

Comment: Let's say the function can be called as `my_summary(df, between(col2, -n, n))` for `n`. Would it be possible to for different `n`s and different columns at the same time? The expected output `n*m`  dataframe/tibble/matrix.